# How to get Date from UTC Date time in power bi?

Tags: powerbi, datetime-format, utc, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-custom-visuals

I'm trying to get UTC Date time to Date in power bi, i have tried in following way but it wont work,

**UTC Date  :** `DateTime.ToText(DateTimeZone.UtcNow(),"yyyyMMdd") --> Throwing Error`

**Local Date:** `DateTime.ToText(DateTime.LocalNow(), "yyyyMMdd") --> 20200508`

The problem here is Local Date i can able to format but UTC Date i'm not able to format why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After tried many time i got one way to work it

```
DateTime.ToText(Date.From(DateTimeZone.FixedUtcNow()),"yyyyMMdd") --> 20200508
```